# Android Sensor Rotation To Degrees

Tags: android, math, sensors

I am using the TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD/TYPE_ACCELEROMETER sensor to basically create a compass.

I call getRotationMatrix  and then remapCoordinateSystem (always landscape) to swap axis and then getOrientation then i take the axis i need currently index 0 and then i call toDegrees and then i make it 0-360 range with

val= (val+ 360) % 360;

Now all works well except that it fluctuate a little bit to much so i went to the search God(google) and lookedup low pass filter theres allot and most dont works so well but i found one that almost work.

newval = oldVal + ALPHA * (newval- oldVal );

Alpha about 0.2-0.5

So now  at 180(-180 in rotation) it quickly jumps to 0 and then it goes to 181(-179 rotation) but if i remove the filter it does not do this.

What can be wrong with the filter or how can i fix this.

Android 2.2 so no TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION or TYPE_ORIENTATION(Deprecated)

thanks

Comment: When faced with a problem like this, it can be informative to log both the samples being input to the filter and the filter output over a period of time encompassing the problem.  Formatting the result into a table and contemplating it will likely help you understand if it's a problem with wraparound, or with really wild sampled data.  Fixing it may be a bit more of a challenge...  Also for thinking about the problem you may find a spreadsheet is useful for posing "what if..." scenarios.

Comment: hi. I added it to excel and made a graph that's how i determined it jumps to 0 after 180. I even drew it on a whiteboard and i still cant understand it. Firstly i thought it was because of the decimal that's messing with it... thanks

Comment: What value do the inputs have when they are rotated slightly beyond 180?  What's the expected next value after 180?  If (and I'm not saying they are, as I haven't looked at the docs recently) 180 and -180 are equivalent, the problem would be that the filter would average those two out to zero.

Comment: sh@t why did i not think of that(last sentence). That might be it makes sense thanks will look at that. Staring at this code for a week now missing stupid things...

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have that orientation angles are periodic. 180 degrees rotation is the same as -180 degrees (as pointed out) is also the same as 540 degrees etc. So while the arithmetic of the low pass filter doesn't change, the number field you need has to be periodic to give you good answers. You're given a rotation matrix representing your orientation, and these matrices make a perfectly good number system. So if you do all your filter arithmetic on the rotation matrices and then only convert to angle at the last minute, your filter will work just fine.